# jQuery mobile radio buttons - persistance of border radius

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, rounded-corners

[In jQuery mobile, the radio buttons get a rounded corner style applied to them.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/index.html)

However, when I use the following code on my mobile website (http://m.fineandcountry.propertylogic.net/) :

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
    <input type='radio' name='p_department' id='p_departmentL' value='RS' checked='checked' onclick='setBuying();'>
    <label for='p_departmentL'>Buying</label>
    <input type='radio' name='p_department' id='p_departmentR' value='RL' onclick='setRenting();'>
    <label for='p_departmentR'>Renting</label>      
</fieldset>
```

I get very inconsistent results -  if I visit on iPad/iPhone (also Chrome on PC), the corners are all rounded:

[Rounded Corners http://i.imm.io/epLF.jpeg](http://i.imm.io/epLF.jpeg)

However if I then click "Search", then click the logo at the top to return to the home page, I get the following (default behavior on Firefox on PC as well):

[image: Correct Behavior]

Is there a rogue piece of JS causing my site to do this? It's been bugging me for a while and all I can find is issues with jQuery Mobile not rounding the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with `mootools.js` and `caption.js`.I am not exactly sure about the root cause of this issue.But loading these two js files after you load `jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js` worked for me. I am not sure if this leads to any other issues.Can you try this and let me know if it works? In the mean while let me see if I can find what really caused the issue.

Comment: Perfect, removing those worked! I didn't need them on the page anyways, so I'd assume it's something to do with noConflict anyways...  thanks a bunch!